# Flexible, consistent and fast Python serialization library

Tags: python, serialization

Specifically, is there a Python 2.7-compatible serialization library that meets the following criteria (most important criteria listed first):

1. Has an API that allows me to **customize serialization** of certain types by providing my own serialization function:

   ```
   # Override serialization of Foo types
   def serialize_foo(pickler, obj):
       pickler.say_hello()     # prints "Hello from pickler at 0x465DED00"
       return pickler.dumps({k: v for k, v in foo.__dict__ if k != 'my_unpicklable_attr'})
   ```

   This API should must also **expose the serializer** itself (i.e. for the `pickler` argument above)

   - `cPickle` fails this requirement
2. The above requirement but for the **deserializer**

   - `cPickle` fails this as its `Unpickler` cannot be subclassed
   - Can be done with `pickle` but messy -- must subclass `Unpickler` and re-implement its `load_reduce()` method
3. Must also handle **circular references**: e.g. must be able to pickle the following `x`:

   ```
   x = {}
   x['ref'] = x
   ```

   - JSON serialization libraries (e.g. `json`, `ujson`) fail this
4. **Consistent**: two separate serialization calls on the same input object must deserialize into the same output object (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376081/pickle-linked-objects) for an example of why this is important). I.e. the following must be `True`

   ```
   unpickler.loads(pickler.dumps(x)) is unpickler.loads(pickler.dumps(x))
   ```

   - `pickle`/`cPickle` achieve this via an internal `memo` dictionary (although this is actually a memory leak because the `memo` never releases objects and only ever grows).
   - AFAIK JSON libraries also fail at this
5. **Fast**: there are plenty of python serialization performance benchmarks on google e.g. [here](https://gist.github.com/cactus/4073643).
   The library needn't be as fast as `msgpack` but should still keep good pace

   - `pickle` lags behind here

**Nice to have**:

6. **Batteries included**: can serialize arbitrary Python objects out-of-the-box

   - e.g. [`dill`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) (but `dill` fails in all the other places `pickle` does because it subclasses `pickle.Pickler`/`Unpickler`)

**Not necessary for now**:

7. **Compatible**: needn't be cross platform compatible. I will only be using this serialization in Python
8. **Secure**: I will be deserializing from trusted sources only
9. **Human-readable**: [Twisted Jelly](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.spread.jelly.html) emphasises this but I just don't care

**My usecase**:

I'm writing a lightweight [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) protocol to stream data between machines in my local network. As such I need to serialize/deserialize objects that are sent on the wire. The twisted API (e.g. [AMP](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.amp.html)/[PB](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/core/howto/pb-usage.html) Jelly) emphasises security (which I don't care about) and trades that off against flexibility and performance (which I do care about). I also find the [Deferred](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html) API very ugly for my purposes.

Comment: As a side note, if you want circular references, you want [YAML](http://yaml.org/).

Comment: @QPaysTaxes thanks but I think YAML fails #4: `file = StringIO(); x = [1, 2, 3]; d = Dumper(file); d.open(); d.represent(x); d.represent(x); file.getvalue()` gives me `'[1, 2, 3]\n--- [1, 2, 3]\n'` which will clearly deserialize to two separate objects as the id of the source object is not serialized.

Comment: I don't speak Python, and I meant the format, not the package.

Comment: Also, I'm fairly sure the reason that happens is because you serialize two objects into it – x, twice. If you serialized [x, x] it would be a single object.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: what you're describing is correct handling of **circular references**. However, I'm talking about consistency of output between calls. This is important because I might choose to serialize `x = [1, 2, 3]` and then later serialize `y = [x, 4, 5, 6]`. When i deserialize, I want to make sure that `y_out[0] is x_out` -- this is what i mean by **consistency**

Comment: I'm 100% certain that if you'd read my original comment, you'd see that it says: "If you want circular references, you want YAML." So, yes, I am describing correct handling of circular references.

Comment: Also, as far as I understand, you're saying "I want the same output for doing the same thing." Any serializer gets you that.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: Not quite: I'm saying that *"I want the same **output object** for serializing the same **input object**"*. I fully understand that YAML handles circular references. What I'm talking about is that I want `y_out[0] is x_out`, where `is`  does not mean equality (`==`) but actually tests that two variables point to the same object in memory. Specifically, `[1, 2, 3] is [1, 2, 3]` will return `False` in Python -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python

Comment: In case I'm not explaining this concept well, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376081/pickle-linked-objects which hits the nail on the head.

Comment: ...That isn't the fault of the markup language. That's the fault of the serializer. Yaml-cpp, for example, offers this functionality; that the Python library doesn't is the Python library's fault. If you can find a serializer that adheres to the standard, anchored nodes will reference the same object.

Comment: For item 4, do you actually mean to use `is` there (i.e., you want object identity, not just equality), or would `==` also be acceptable?

Comment: @jwodder - yes, I want object identity thanks